# Extract root and intermediate cert from fullchain into separate file

Tags: ansible, openssl, client-certificates

Is there an possibility via an openssl command or via an ansible module
to extract only the root an intermediate cert from a fullchain file which includes server, intermediate and root certificate e.g:

fullchain.crt:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----

.
.

SERVER CRT

.
.

-----END CERTIFICATE -----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----

.
.

INTERMEDIATE CERT

.
.

-----END CERTIFICATE -----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----

.
.

ROOT CERT

.
.

-----END CERTIFICATE -----
```

What I want is to extract from the fullchain only the root and intermediate cert into another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

### OpenSSL:

```bash
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile fullchain.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout
```

Something like the afore mentioned would be possible to give you what you're looking for as will generate the subject and issuer.

#### AWK:

```bash
awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/{flag=1}/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{print;flag=0}flag' fullchain.crt | tail -n +4 > root_intermediate.crt
```

#### Ansible:

```yaml
- name: Extract Root and Intermediate Certificates
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: >
      awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/{flag=1}/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{print;flag=0}flag' {{ fullchain_path }} | tail -n +4 > {{ output_path }}
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: shell_output
```

Basically is the AWK Method using shell

I vote for either 1st or 2nd as for Ansible I rather to avoid as much as possibly can the use of `ansible.builtin.shell` as recommended by Best Practices.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [community.crypto](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/index.html) Ansible collection. Most likely it even has a specific module that will complete your task. Also, its `*_info` modules typically can return a dictionary with the certificate data.

Comment: already did that but didn't find a module for exact these scenario